# how show/list snaphosts by "description" in GoogleCloud?

Tags: google-compute-engine

Any idea how to show "snapshots descriptions" in Google Cloud ?
When I am creating a snapshot, there is option to make description about this snapshot, however I just realized that after that I don't see this "snapshots description" in the list, also not found how to list via gcloud command
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the snapshot description via console by clicking on the name of your snapshot from the Snapshots page (Compute Engine > Snapshots) and going to the details of that snapshot.

You can also view the description of your snapshot through the [gcloud compute snapshots describe command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/snapshots/describe).

```
gcloud compute snapshots describe [SNAPSHOT_NAME]
```

Comment: OK this is some workaround, but my complain was that u don't see descriptions about snapshots in "main view" so u are missing some quick overview about all snaps.
ok seems that this is not a bug, this is a feature :)